# The search input bar html markup at center is missing when I fetch the results

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

Iam new to web development and iam learning to build webapplications please help me

my HTML,CSS and javascript code is given below :

```js
const Input = document.getElementById("Input")
const button = document.getElementById('submit')
const dataBox = document.getElementById('dataBox')

function isValidUrl(url) {
    var regExp = /((http|https):\/\/)(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#?&//=]*)?/;
    return url.match(regExp) !== null;
}


Input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    let url = event.target.value
    isValidUrl(url) ? button.disabled = false : button.disabled = true;
})

button.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let url = Input.value;
    if (isValidUrl(url)) {

        try {
            // converting data in to Form-encode format in the body
            const data = new URLSearchParams();
            data.append('url', url)

            const response = await fetch("./testValues.json")
    
            const tagsObject =await response.json()

            const tagsArray = await tagsObject.keywords

            
            let row = null
            await tagsArray.forEach((element,index) => {

                if((index) % 3 ===0){

                    row ? dataBox.append(row) : ""
                    row = document.createElement('div')
                    row.classList.add('row')
                    row.classList.add('row-cols-1')
                    row.classList.add('row-cols-sm-2')
                    row.classList.add('row-cols-md-3')
                } 
                const column = document.createElement('div')
                column.classList.add('col')
                column.classList.add('set-border')
                column.innerText = element;
                row.append(column);

            });

            
            
        } catch (error) {
            
            console.log(error)
            
        }


    }
    else {
        event.target.disabled = true;
    }
})
```

```css
.hide{
    display: none;
}
.dark-background{
    background-color: #212529;
    color: #9ca3ab;
}

.dark-background-focus:focus{
    background-color: #212529;
    color: #9ca3ab;
}


.center{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
}

.button-outline-visible{
    border-color: #cd5c5c;
    color: #9ca3ab;
}

.button-outline-visible:hover{
    background-color: #cd5c5c;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.set-border{
    margin: 1rem;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>  tags viewer</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/08/11/12/32/-884381_1280.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
    <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body class="dark-background center container">

        <form>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="Input" class="form-label">Enter The URL Of  </label>
                <input class="form-control dark-background dark-background-focus" type="text" id="Input" placeholder="Default input" aria-label="default input example">
                <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text dark-background">enter the url of the   for the   tags</div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-outline button-outline-visible" disabled>Get Tags</button>
            <div id="dataBox" class="m-auto container text-center">
        </form>

    
    
</div>
    
        
    </body>
</html>
```

my file containing json is : testValues.json

and the content in the file is

```
{
    "keywords": [
        "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6", "value7", "value8", "value9", "value9", "value10", "value11", "value12", "value13", "value14", "value15", "value16", "value17", "value18", "value19", "value20", "value21", "value22", "value23", "value24", "value25", "value26", "value27"
    ]
}
```

initially my page looks like this :
[initial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUtxG.png)

but when I click on Get tags button I get the output like this :
[after fetch request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY5SH.png)

**MY PROBLEM :** you can see that the search bar got disappeared and I am unable to scroll to it

I am new to web development so please give some suggestions or help me to solve this problem any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi, why you append your div(row ? dataBox.append(row) : "") then make a element(row = document.createElement('div'))?

Comment: Hello, @dmaon I want to create a new row for every three coloumns so I used this piece of code to do that Iam using bootstrap in this

Comment: I think you can set a class for your parent div to be a grid with 3 or more columns and in your append, add a simple div to be together, see this [sample](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/features/)... I see now, your dataBox div hasn't closeted.

Comment: try [this](https://playcode.io/1510453)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @dmaon i have tried your demo code and sorry I should have checked to close the div tag my bad i have overlooked that

Comment: @dmaon if you add these styles in your code and and add the set-border style on the button element in the modified code which you have provided then also the top part is getting cut could you check that please 

the css : 
.button-outline-visible:hover{
    background-color: #cd5c5c;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.set-border{
    margin: 1rem;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}

Comment: once see this picture @dmaon after adding some values to the keywords array and setting the styles of button-outline-visible:hover and set-border I got the following result : https://photos.app.goo.gl/JvNQ2eWGuvu3Xpo29

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but this is because of your "display: flex" on the ".center" class name, see [this](https://playcode.io/1510453)